# scipy: how to get all non-zero value index for each row?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I can't find more info about scipy.sparse indexing except SciPy v0.11 Reference Guide, which says that

```
The lil_matrix class supports basic slicing and fancy indexing with a similar syntax to NumPy arrays.
```

. I have read numpy document about index, but I didn't understand it clearly, for example,

```
Asp = sparse.lil_matrix((3,3))
Asp.setdiag(zeros(3))
Asp[0, 1:3] = 10
print Asp.todense()
```

1.
why the output is

```
[[  0.  10.  10.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]]
```

what does [0,1:3] meaning? if I use

```
Asp[0, 1:2,3] = 10
```

there's a error:

```
IndexError: invalid index
```

, I don't know the reason.

2.what's the fastest way to get all non-zero values for each row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your second question, use the `nonzero()` method. I had to dig through [the source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.11.0/scipy/sparse/base.py#L415) to find it, since I couldn't find it in any of the reference documentation.

```
def nonzero(self):
    """nonzero indices

    Returns a tuple of arrays (row,col) containing the indices
    of the non-zero elements of the matrix.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
    >>> A = csr_matrix([[1,2,0],[0,0,3],[4,0,5]])
    >>> A.nonzero()
    (array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2]), array([0, 1, 2, 0, 2]))

    """
```

Comment: @Jaime, very nice. Odd that I couldn't find that it's a method available to `scipy.sparse` matrixes, as well, but maybe that's  assumed?

Comment: @fizzisist MY bad, I should read things with more care... A lot of the sparse matrix methods are listed, with very little documentation, in the **Methods** section of the corresponding sparse matrix class documentation. If you scroll down [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html), you will get to it, and `nonzero` is part of the list, linking to [this page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.nonzero.html) that is not linked elsewhere that I know of, so definitely hard to find.

Answer (score 2):

> what does `[0,1:3]` mean?

That means: row 0, elements `1` to `3` (exclusive). Since Numpy and Scipy use zero-based indices, row 0 is the first row and `1:3` denotes the first and second column.

`Asp[0, 1:2,3]` is invalid because you've got three indices, `0`, `1:2` and `3`. Matrices only have two axes.

This is all standard Numpy stuff; read any good tutorial on that package.

Comment: thank you. could you tell me what's the fastest way to get all non-zero values for each row?